# OBIEE 11g : Scheduling Reports based on filter

Tags: obiee

I need my OBIEE Analysis report to be sent to 200 people( all are from different departments) through Actionable Intelligence Agent .
I need to filter the data based on department and send it. I was unable to put the condition in Agent.

Can I filter the data in Dashboard prompt and link the Agent with Dashboard??
Will this work out or any other suggestion for this case??

Answer (score 1):

For those "filter by X and send it to Y" scenarios the best way (in my opinion) is to use BI Publisher bursting options. It's just the textbook case for that.

If you have to stick to the agents in OBIEE, consider enabling row level security for that data following your requirements. Then just configure the agent to send the analysis to the required people and row level sec should do the rest.

If row level security is too much effort, I guess you could play with some auxiliary analysis to filter your main report based on the department of the user. The idea would be the following:

1. Create a report with the department column in the criteria and a filter by user where the user id is equal to the presentation variable @{user.id} (this is a meta variable that is always available and contains the user logged in).
2. Filter your main report with a condition where department is based on the results of another analysis (the previous one), so it will return the right department for each user.
3. Configure your agent to be sent as recipient (not as a specific user) and use the analysis in point 2 as the content to be delivered
4. Set your 200 recipients manually or use a condition report to get them
5. Make sure that both analysis in points 1 and 2 are saved in a place where all the users can read them.

I'm quite sure that it will work too :)

Though to be clear, my first option will be BIP bursting followed by proper row level sec.

Hope it helps!